# Had some mold due to water leak. Cleaned and patched dry wall but still concerned

Tags: drywall, leak, mold, rot

Pictures: https://imgur.com/a/2kjInat

There was a small leak from the bathroom above that I noticed only after a couple of weeks. The leak came from the supply line to the toilet, I had tried to attach a T fitting for the bidet and I hadn't tightened it enough. The leak caused the drywall in the ceiling to bulge. I fixed the leak and cut open the drywall. I cleaned as much as I could (cleaning solution shown in photos) and replaced the insulation. I kept it open for a few days to make sure leak is addressed and then I patched up the drywall.

But now, I am starting to doubt if I did enough to kill all the mold. Should I have cut open more of the drywall? Should I have used something stronger? Should I have called an expert? Do the pictures tell if the mold was very bad and are my concerns warranted? Before I sand it down and paint, I wanted to get some opinions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it's going to cause you to loose sleep, then open it up, clean it more, let it dry until you're comfortable, then button it all up again. If that seems like too much effort, then you really don't have anything to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you've fixed the condition that would sustain mold, it's fine. Leaving it open for a few days was wise. The water from anti-mold treatments can remain long after the treatment has long lost its potency. It would have been a mistake to close it if the area was still wet, but I wouldn't reopen it even then unless it was *very* wet when I mistakenly closed it.